# How to pass ConnectionString from appsettings.json file to class library project in dot net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0, .net-core-2.2

I have two projects in my solution. One is an angular core 2.2 web application and other is a class library project which contains the domain models and the dbcontext.
I want to pass the connection string to dbcontext so that i can create the database using the code first approach.
this is my connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DataConnection": "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;"
```

this the code in the ConfigureService Method

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<TestContext>(context => context.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

}

And this is my DBContext

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
 public CCPGV1Context(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {

    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I am new to code first approach as well as dot net core. Please guide me what should i do !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are configuring your connection string as a service, you could simply inject the constructor of your `DbContext` class like this:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext 
  { 
  public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options):base(options)
         {

         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `IConfiguration` interface as a parameter, from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` to the contructor of `Startup` class (name it whatever, for example purposes, I will call it `_configuration`).

Then, replace this line

```
services.AddDbContextPool<TestContext>(context => context.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection")));
```

with this one:

```
services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection")));
```

After thar, add this constructor to you `TestContext` class:

```
public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
```

This for seed the `DBContextOptions` class with the configuration stablished for `TestContext` in `Startup.cs`